# Cannot read property "0" of undefined in array

Tags: javascript

Im making a small game where I move a ball onDeviceOrientation into holes. I generate holes(circles) in canvas and push them into an array called holes. When I'm trying to check for collision, the declared value `let currentHole = this.holes[i];`  shows this error. Can you tell me why the property of 0 is undefined? I couldn't understand checking other people's problems.

this is my JS code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
const hole = canvas.getContext('2d');
let scoreCount = 0;
let holes = [];
var hx = Math.random() * canvas.width;
var hy = Math.random() * canvas.height;
var radius = 25;
var sAngle = 0;
var eAngle = 2 * Math.PI;
let speedX = 0;
let speedY = 0;
let x = 200;
let y = 200;
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', onDeviceOrientationChange);
const restart = document.querySelector('.restart');
document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', onStartClick);
function onStartClick() {
  const btn = document.querySelector('.start');
  btn.classList.add('remove');
  restart.classList.remove('remove');
  const score = document.createElement('span');
  score.classList.add('score');
  score.innerHTML = 'SCORE: ' + scoreCount;
  document.body.appendChild(score);
  let ball = document.createElement('div');
  ball.classList.add('ball');
  document.body.appendChild(ball);
  makeHoles();
  onDeviceOrientationChange(event);
  checkForCollision();
}
function onDeviceOrientationChange(event) {
  let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');
  speedX = event.alpha / 60; //alpha nie 
  speedY = event.beta / 60;
  if ((innerWidth > speedX + x > 0)) {
    x += speedX;
    ball.style.left = x + 'px';
  }
  if (window.innerHeight > speedY + y > 0) {
    y += speedY;
    ball.style.top = y + 'px';
  }
}
function makeHoles() {
  for (let i = 1; i < canvas.width / 100; i++) {
    hole.beginPath();
    hole.arc(
      hx,
      hy,
      radius,
      sAngle,
      eAngle,
    );
    hole.fillStyle = 'rgb(84, 93, 139)';
    hole.fill();
    hole.stroke();
    hole.closePath();
    holes.push(hole);
  }
  console.log(holes);
}
function checkForCollision() {
  for (let i = 0; i < holes.length; i++) {
    let currentHole = this.holes[i];
    let ball = document.querySelector('.ball');

    currentHole = {
      radius: radius,
      x: hx,
      y: hy
    };
    ball = {
      radius: 15,
      x: x,
      y: y
    };

    var dx = currentHole.x - ball.x;
    var dy = currentHole.y - ball.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (distance < currentHole.radius + ball.radius) {
      scoreCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.holes` is undefined. Use `holes` instead.

Comment: This is not a [mcve]

Comment: thank you it worked but now i see that instead of generating several holes it only creates only one :|

Comment: Your code adds the `hole` reference to the canvas context over and over again. `.push()` does not make a copy (and it would make no sense anyway to copy the canvas context).

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'holes[i]', not 'this.holes[i]'.